# No me encuentra los recursos de un proyecto en eclipse

Tags: java

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de un juego en java para un proyecto de clase. Lo que pasa es que me da errores el código que saco desde su pagina principal(el original).
Se supone que no debería fallarme pero he buscado por todas partes y no doy con la tecla.
Aquí dejo el enlace donde he sacado el código original de su Github y me falla aun así como he comentado.

[Enlace Github](https://github.com/javadevone/juego-2d-java)

```
public static Font cargarFuente(final String ruta) {
    Font fuente = null;

    InputStream entradaBytes = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(ruta);

    try {
        fuente = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, entradaBytes);
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fuente = fuente.deriveFont(12f);

    return fuente;
}
```

Me aparece el siguiente error al ejecutarlo.

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1208)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1076)
at principal.herramientas.CargadorRecursos.cargarFuente(CargadorRecursos.java:102)
at principal.Constantes.<clinit>(Constantes.java:43)
at principal.GestorPrincipal.main(GestorPrincipal.java:43)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at principal.GestorPrincipal.main(GestorPrincipal.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.Font.deriveFont(float)" 
because "fuente" is null
at principal.herramientas.CargadorRecursos.cargarFuente(CargadorRecursos.java:109)
at principal.Constantes.<clinit>(Constantes.java:43)
... 1 more
```

Estoy algo agobiado porque es para un proyecto que tengo que terminar pronto y ya no se que hacer.
En principio creía que erra fallo de la fuente pero si quito la fuente me da errores en las imágenes y demás recursos. He visto que puede acceder a los recursos correctamente (que java los ve) pero ya no tengo idea.
Muchas gracias a todos.

Os dejo imágenes por si puede ayudar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quito la fuente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, agrega un ejemplo de como tratas de cargarlos. No olvides revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "java.awt.Font.deriveFont(float)"  because "fuente" is null

se produce en tu método para cargar la fuente ya que es incorrecto en este punto:

```
   fuente = fuente.deriveFont(12f);
```

debes definir una fuente "base" para poder asignar el tamaño o el estilo, modifica tu método de esta forma:

```
public static Font cargarFuente(final String ruta) {
        Font fuente = null;

        InputStream entradaBytes = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(ruta);

        try {

                    Font fuenteBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, entradaBytes);
                    entradaBytes.close();
                    fuente = fuenteBase.deriveFont(12f);

        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //fuente = fuente.deriveFont(12f);

        return fuente;
    }
```

Comment: Ahora me sigue dando error pero en las imagenes. Has probado el juego a ver si funciona en tu ordenador ? Gracias por responder.  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1402)`